# Как создать предикат?

Tags: prolog

Не получается создать предикат, удаляющий из списка все элементы с четных позиций.
Есть у кого-то какие-то идеи?

Comment: да, конечно идеи есть.

Comment: @Grundy Можете поделиться? В прологе мало чего понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не получается создать предикат, удаляющий из списка все элементы с четных позиций.

Решение:

```
remove_even([], []).
remove_even([X], [X]).
remove_even([ Odd, Even | Xs ],[ Odd | Ys ]):-
    remove_even( Xs, Ys ).
```